# Connecting a second monitor via DisplayLink on Debian

Tags: debian, display, xrandr, displaylink

**Problem:**
I am unable to connect my second monitor.

**Background:**
I freshly installed [DebianStretch](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStretch) on my desktop computer. Before this, I was running Windows 10 on my host and Debian in a virtual machine. Since my computer only has one HDMI-output, I used an [adapter](https://i-tec.cz/en/produkt/u3dualada-2/) (USB 3.0 to HDMI) and it worked just fine.
Now, however, the second monitor won't get recognized, and I have been trying to get it to work for hours.

**What I tried**:
At first, I installed the DisplayLink drivers via [displaylink-debian](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian). Since `xrandr --listproviders` only showed one provider, I tried to change `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-displaylink.conf` like recommended [here](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian/issues/228#issuecomment-467889348) and [here](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian/issues/236#issuecomment-471213411). In the end, I simply removed the config file. Now, `xrandr --listproviders` shows the following output:

```
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x80 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 2 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x41 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
```

At this point, `gnome-control-center display` still only showed one monitor, so I tried to set the provider sources like that:

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 0 0
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0
```

**Result**:
This, at least, made Display show both monitors. However, when I try to enable that as my secondary display, it only works for half a second, and then everything freezes and I have to manually force a shutdown.